# jquery results not being echoed to div on same page

Tags: php

been trying to figure out how to echo a query result to a textbox in a div. I have a form (see below) and it does place the result in a textbox as I want but is not echoing back to the div (which is called 'content'). I've updated the code for my HTML here after some edits:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="search" method="post" action="rating.php">Miles <input name="miles" id="miles" type="text" /> <input name="search1" id="search1" class="btnButton" value="Search" type="submit" /></form>
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/javasript" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

//jquery click event
$("#search").on("submit", function(e){

   //disable default form submit postpage
   e.preventDefault();

   //make ajax call to the search.php parsing the search textbox value as query string
   $.get("rating.php?miles="+$("#miles").val(), function(result){

        //Result will be dumped in the div
        $("#content").html(result);

       });

   });

});
// ]]></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The value of miles is now passed to rating.php where I want it to do a query and then format the result in a textbox format that is displayed in the div:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'somehost.com';
$username = 'ratetable';
$password = 'mypassword';

$miles = (int) $_POST['miles'];

try 
{
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=ratetable", $username, $password);

foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage<={$miles} ORDER BY mileage DESC LIMIT 1") as $row) {
 $result= "<input type='text' name='answer' value='" . $row['ratepermile'] . "'>'";
 echo $result;

   }
}         

catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  throw($e); 
}
?>
```

The result is formatted the way I want, except that it is not being echoed back to the script and placed where the result should be. Is there a way I can use div tags or otherwise ensure it's going to a specific div?

Thank you for looking.

Comment: In my experience with calling php files with javascript i have learned one thing. It will be a pain in the ass in the future.

Comment: So if i were you i would just use the action attribuut instead to call the php file

Comment: Are you getting a javascript or php error or both?

Comment: @Mrillwind - what do you mean action attribute? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: @Pitchinnate - no errors. Just no results so I can't figure out if no number is being sent or if the way I'm formatting my output is wrong.

Comment: @Shawn do you have something like firebug installed on your browser so you can look at the console and see the request to see if it is correct?

Comment: `<form  method="post" action="process.php" >` This way after pressing submit you will be referred to process.php.
And as @Pitchinnate said firebug is a good way to see if the request is going as you intend.

Comment: Hi there - wow, well, found Firebug and installed it in Firefox. I got this error in the script but don't know what it means because, quite frankly, I was following an example that I assumed was a working example: ReferenceError: $ is not defined. So this is probably what is choking the script I suppose?

Comment: OK that error is gone. Revised question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing comes to mind: you're not including the jQuery library anywhere in the example.
Also, notice the comma on the following line should be a dot:

> e,preventDefault();

If that's not the problem but just the result of hasty copy / pasting, are sure that your $.get() request is giving you any output at all?

You probably also want to change the following:

> $("#search").live("click", function(e){

to something like:

> $("#search").on("submit", function(e){

because the reference of #search is pointing to your form-tag rather than to a button

Comment: Hi kvdv, I can't tell if the value is being passed. I'm trying this jquery stuff and still not sure. If there is output, no output is being sent.

Comment: Still nothing. Am I structuring my output right so it goes to the div?

Comment: Your javascript seems fine now; it works for me when under the condition that "rating.php" exists in the same folder.
The PHP issue seems to be that you're putting a variable ($miles) into a string that is single quoted.
That should be either double-quoted, with the variable surrounded by {} like such: .."mileage<={$miles} ORDER BY".. or like such: ..'mileage<='.{$miles}.' ORDER BY'..

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm doing this right. I tried the following: foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM rates WHERE 'mileage<='.{$miles}.' ORDER BY mileage DESC LIMIT 1') as $row) {   and still doesn't like it.

Comment: OK figured out what the problem was but it's still not going to the div

Comment: Ok you're gonna be able to laugh about this someday... The error is on this line: 
`<script type="text/javasript" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>`
Javascript is misspelled (missing the letter c) and therefore your javascript isn't being executed at all!

Comment: (face palm) Yargh! Thanks kv!